# Opera 12.14 border-radius on <input /> not working

Tags: html, css, input, opera, textinput

I am trying to make a simple login kind of page and trying to make it cross browser and, tho I am still at the beginning, I already found a problem that I don't find any answer at.
I am trying to make some text inputs and submit input buttons with rounded corners but it won't let me do it and I don't know why and it won't apply on the  `<input />` tag at all.

I tried both border-radius simply, as opera has already built in the standardized parameter and even -o-border-radius but it won't work either way.
I am working with `em` instead of `px`, but I tried both, as I thought that could be the problem, but it's not it.

So I'm kinda really clueless; opera doesn't support it on the  tag?

Other than that it is working in the following browsers: Internet Explorer 9 (with the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` line inserted in the head of the html/php file), Mozzila Firefox 19.0, Google Chrome 25.0, Safari 5.1, Maxthon Cloud Browser 4.0

I also tried to make it with a clean code, meaning just some `<input />` tags and the css file and it didn't work.

I hope somebody can give me a reasonable response for this.

Comment: Can you show us your css code?

Comment: Sure. Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/AeEsV/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border style is **required**!

Add to:

```
.textBox {
   border-style: solid;
}
```

My advice is to use shorthand property for the `border`:

Example: `border: 3px solid #cc0000;`

More information about `border` properties at: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

Comment: So as I understand the browser itself doesn't support it. Well that is a shame... Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes it does! I've tested it in `Oprea 12.02`: [__FIDDLE__](http://jsfiddle.net/AeEsV/1/)

Comment: Oh no, I mean the `border-radius` itself without any solid border.